# What specific properties are required to submit job on remote yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We are trying to submit a spark/map-red job to a remote yarn cluster and we know to submit that we would require core-site and yarn-site xmls at conf directory.But I am trying to understand what specific properties is need for yarn client and spark client to submit job remotely.I don't want to share all the properties.
Any pointers to this would help.

Answer (score 0):

We generally call it Edge Node or Gateway Node and following files must be available under Hadoop and yarn configuration.

```
#hadoop folder
core-site.xml
hadoop-env.sh
hdfs-site.xml
log4j.properties
```

Yarn configuration

```
#yarn folder
core-site.xml
hadoop-env.sh
hdfs-site.xml
log4j.properties
mapred-site.xml
yarn-site.xml
```

Attaching a sample screenshot.

[image: refer cloudera based edge node]

Comment: This i understand but was looking for specific conf properties that is need for job submission.